# SwiftUI, UITests, issue with testing View that its existence relies on UserDefault's property

Tags: swiftui, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I am trying to write UITests for the Onboarding view for my SwiftUI based application.

```swift
func testOnboarding() {
        @AppStorage("shouldShowOnboarding") var shouldShowOnboarding: Bool = true
        
        shouldShowOnboarding = true
        defer {
            shouldShowOnboarding = false
        }
        
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        
        let pageOne = app.staticTexts["pageOne"]
        
        XCTAssert(pageOne.exists)
    }
```

Unfortunately, switching shouldShowOnboarding to true has no effect on the app. I wonder why is that? Is it too late for this toggle to take effect?

How can I resolve it?

For clarity, here is the simplified version of the view:

```swift
struct FSTabView: View {
    @AppStorage(FSOperationalString.appStorageShouldShowOnboarding) var shouldShowOnboarding: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView {
                Rectangle()
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $shouldShowOnboarding, content: {
                OnboardingTab(shouldPresentOnboarding: $shouldShowOnboarding)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UI test cannot access the code under test. UI tests access you app like the user does using the accessibility features of iOS. So you need to find a way to set the user defaults value from outside of our app. You could do that for example with a launch parameter. This is why I always say that SwiftUI code is not testable.

Comment: Hey dasdom, thanks for getting back to me. Can you elaborate on SwiftUI code is not testable part? I've written some tests and for the most part, SwiftUI app seems to be pretty testable.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is ok to paste a link to my blog here. But here we go: https://dasdom.dev/testing-the-untestable/

Comment: Well, theoretically it should be working via user defaults arguments domain (like `app.launchArguments = ["-shouldShowOnboarding true"]`, set before launch), but due to a Xcode bug launch arguments now are not propagated to launched testing app. You can file one more feedback to Apple.

Comment: Hey Asperi, is bug on Xcode 13 only?

Comment: My launchArguments are working fine in Xcode 13 :shrug:

Comment: Hey Mike, mine is not working, as mentioned above, could you please share some pieces of your code? Maybe I am doing something wrong. I set ["-shouldShowOnboarding 1"] for the app launch but it takes no effect.